# I have installed ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit, but it still not opening after installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 alongside Windows 8 (pre-installed,default in laptop). After installing and restarting, only Windows 8 opens, I don't see Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUPERGRUB2 disk to let search for your bootable OS on you computer.
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ (Try first)

After succesfully starting your two operating system, you can install a new GRUB in your boot sector (fixing and replacing)

Comment: The OP almost certainly has an EFI installation of Windows, but Linux might be installed in BIOS mode. It appears that Super GRUB 2 Disk doesn't (yet) support EFI-mode booting. Thus, although Super GRUB 2 Disk might get Linux booted, this won't really solve the underlying problem, which is the mixed mode (BIOS and EFI) of the OS installations.